# Highrise API - how to work with XML and manipulate variables

Tags: php, xml, api, parsing

Using curl with an api token and getting the XML elements into working variables or to at least view in html format.

Here is the code used that is doing a vardump:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://mywebsite.highrisehq.com/people.xml');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,'myapitoken12345:x');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);

$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);  

$people_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
var_dump($people_xml);
```

When doing the var_dump, the output isn't something I am familiar with.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement) #1 (2) { 
["@attributes"]=> array(1) { 
["type"]=> string(5) "array" } 
["person"]=> array(128) { ...  etc. etc. etc...
```

The XML structure that HighriseHQ.com shows is like this for clues on how to retrieve elements.

```
<people type="array">
  <person>
  <first-name>John</first-name>
  </person>
  <person>
  <first-name>Jane</first-name>
  </person>
</people>
  .... etc. etc.
```

How or where do I translate the part that says `$people = simplexml_load_string($xml);` into variables that I can work with?  Eventually I want to either display, edit, or store those people as i'll be syncing a website database with highrise - so that notes, and contacts aren't outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
$curl = curl_init('https://my_website_goes_here.highrisehq.com/people.xml');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'my_api_token_goes_here:x');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$people_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

foreach($people_xml->person as $person) {
    echo "<strong>" . $person->{'first-name'} . " " . $person->{'last-name'} . "</strong><br />";
    echo "Title: " . $person->{'title'} . "<br />";
    echo "Background: " . $person->{'background'} . "<br />";
    echo "Email: " . $person->{'email-address'} . "<br />";
    echo "ID: " . $person->id . "<br /><br />";
}
```